# Xamarin.Essentials WebAuthenticator cannot capture redirect data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

im trying to register over WebAuthenticator my mobile app with twitch but im stuck by getting data back from from WebAuthenticator.

WebAuthenticator:

```
WebAuthenticatorResult authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
                    new Uri("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id={ ClientID }&redirect_uri=https://com.anderssoft.twitchviewer/&response_type=token&scope={ Scope }"),
                    new Uri("https://com.anderssoft.twitchviewer/"));

var accesToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
```

IntentFilter :

```
    [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "com.anderssoft.twitchviewer")]
    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
    }
```

AndroidManifest added:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Without added lines in manifest it will recieve callback but end in nullref and with the lines it stucks in app with returned data from twitch but the filter did not recieve it.
Ive tried it multiple ways and dont know whats next...

App goes from Android 8-11

Comment: Could you please post a full error log about this problem?

Comment: There is no real error. The intent filter wont handle the recieved Response from twitch. I See the Response for example : https://com.anderssoft.twitchviewer/#acesstoken=1234567     but it the intent filter didnt fire. Without the Manifest Lines it recieve the data but will endlich in nullref

Comment: after hours of reserch i found a way to run it without  the manifest lines. My problem i have used xamarin essentials v 1.6.1 and on this version was a bug what causes the nullref. The only think what disturbs is wenn the callback is fired it will ask for "open with" where i must select my app too continue and i think whit the CustomTabsService it wont ask me. But it stucks in tab whit redirect from Twitch.